# Android - Parsing Twitter JSON for image url

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, twitter

I'm currently trying to put a twitter feed into my app and currently everything works except when I try to get the image url field from the JSON returned.

Here is my code to parse the JSON:

```
      public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets() {
      String searchUrl =
          "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vogella.json";

      ArrayList<Tweet> tweets =
            new ArrayList<Tweet>();

      HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

      ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler =
            new BasicResponseHandler();

      String responseBody = null;
      try {
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

      JSONObject jsonObject = null;

      Log.e("", "responseBody = " + responseBody);


    JSONArray arr = null;
    try {
        arr = new JSONArray(responseBody);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Tweet tweet = null;
            try {
                tweet = new Tweet(
                      jsonObject.getString("profile_image_url"),
                      jsonObject.getString("text"),
                      jsonObject.getString("created_at")
                );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }

      return tweets;
    }
```

And here is the error I get:

```
02-14 00:19:18.672: W/System.err(809): org.json.JSONException:JSONObject["profile_image_url"] not found.
```

Despite the "profile_image_url" being present - click the link to see the JSON - [LINK](http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vogella.json). Everything else in the feed appears to be retrievable so why cant I get the image url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jsonObject` variable refers to the top level array element of your response, which contains elements like `in_reply_to_status_id`, `geo`, etc. The `profile_image_url` property is not a property in that top level array element, but rather a child element of the `user` property.

```
[
    {
        "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
        ...
        "geo":null,
        "user":
            {   
                "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/112136794\/twilk_background_4c1620bca9ed3.jpg",
                ...
            }
    },
    ...
]
```

To access the `profile_background_image_url`, you would have to do something roughly like the following:

```
JSONObject userObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("user");
String url = userObject.getString("profile_image_url");
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the cause:

```
[
   {
     "user":{
          "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1249241027    \/LarsVogel10_normal.png",
      },
      "created_at":"Mon Feb 13 22:34:09 +0000 2012",
      "text":"Fun evening at speaker dinner at #jfokus."
   },
   {
..
...
```

profile_image_url is under "user", while "text" and "created_at" are above

Answer (score 1):

I'm *PRETTY* sure that to do this you have to read the JSON from the URL that has the 'profile_image_url' variable. The `twitter.com/statuses/` URL doesn't have that variable I don't think. [This](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name) shows that the 'profile_image_url' is at `/profile_images/`. Just letting you know that changing your URL to that might be able to find it. :P